# react-native-elements FormInput cannot be imported

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

Seems like I am not allowed to import FormInput from react-native-elements.

I got this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `LoginForm`.
```

My code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { FormInput, Button } from 'react-native-elements'

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <FormInput value="" placeholder="Enter email"></FormInput>
          <FormInput valye="" placeholder="Enter password"></FormInput>
          <Button title="Login" backgroundColor="red"></Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't see what I am doing differently from the official [doc](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html). I know FormInput is the issue because if I comment out the two lines then it renders fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FormInput** only exists in **0.19.1** version of React-Native-Elements.

Make sure you have properly installed the version **0.19.1** using the code below in the terminal,

```
npm -i react-native-elements@0.19.1
```

Here is more information for **0.19.1** elements,
[0.19.1 Input](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html)

However, you can also keep using the 1.0.0 version of react-native-elements.
For **1.0.0**, the input component is a little different.
Here is the link about input elements in React-Native,
[1.0.0 Input](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

`FormInput` has been Changed to `Input` from v1.0.0-beta onwards

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements'

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Input value="" placeholder="Enter email"></Input>
          <Input valye="" placeholder="Enter password"></Input>
          <Button title="Login" backgroundColor="red"></Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

this should work.

More info [here](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/855)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Fatih Aktaş answered first so I am accepting his answer